# When using the Pocket API in an iOS app, is retrieval of articles only handled through JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, ios5, ios6

For those that have integrated Pocket into an app (further than just saving articles, I need to retrieve) when you go to retrieve a list of the users articles, is it only handled through JSON ([as discussed here](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve)), or can you do it somehow with the [Objective-C SDK](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/sdk/objective-c) directly?

If so, would I just be best off using a JSON framework to integrate it into my app?

I only ask because there appears to be a native way to save articles, and I was hoping there was a way to retrieve them as well, but I can't seem to find anything about it listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the [source of the SDK on Github](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK/), you'll see there is a [method to call any API](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK/blob/master/SDK/PocketAPI.h#L88). So it does appear that you can use the SDK to do more than just share.

---

**Edit:** You'd probably need to do something like this (untested code)

```
NSDictionary* argumentDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"010101", @"consumer_key",
                                    @"101010", @"access_token",
                                    @"simple", @"detailType", nil]; //etc
[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod:@"get"
                      withHTTPMethod:@"POST"
                           arguments:argumentDictionary
                             handler:^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error){
    // handle response here!
}];
```

Comment: How would I do this exactly?